# List the details of the senior employee belongs to a certain year

Tags: sqlite

I wish to obtain in sqlite :

**List the details of the senior employee belongs to 1981**

But the

```
select  *  from emp where hiredate in (select min(hiredate) from emp   
where  to_char( hiredate,’YYYY’) = ‘1981’)
```

not working. I suppose the to_char function is not recognized.

I've tried

```
select min(hiredate) from table   
where hiredate IN ('1981%')
```

result `NULL`

I mention the date is in the sqlite supported format ; `yyyy-mm-dd`

Thank you in advance!  :))))

Comment: `to_char()` is not a sqlite function, no. https://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html etc.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the `hiredate`'s format is `YYYY-MM-DD` since this is the only format that is directly comparable and can be manipulated as a date in SQLite (although it is actually `TEXT`).
If so, then use `LIKE` operator like this:

```
select * from emp 
where hiredate = (select min(hiredate) from emp where hiredate like '1981%')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the earliest hire date in 1981, just use

```
SELECT *
FROM emp
WHERE hiredate LIKE '1981-%'
ORDER BY hiredate
LIMIT 1;
```

which sorts all the rows with 1981 hire dates by that date and only returns the first (minimum) one.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of to_char () you can use the strftime function.
strftime ('% Y', hiredate)

`SELECT MIN(hiredate) FROM  table  WHERE STRFTIME ('% Y', hiredate) = '1981'`